# Replace first column on a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have the following file.

```
101; John Bauer;      811-7780831;
102; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627; 
102; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627;
103; Arnold Sipes;    866-4343123;
104; Donald Quinn;    877-2828732;
105; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
105; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
105; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
```

I'm trying to use `sed` to replace the first column of the file with auto increment values, starting with one. The the final output should be something like this.

```
1; John Bauer;      811-7780831;
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627; 
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627;
3; Arnold Sipes;    866-4343123;
4; Donald Quinn;    877-2828732;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
```

If the first value of the first column repeats, it should assign the same value, hence the duplicate values on the "output" file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Perl:

```
perl -F\; -lane 'BEGIN {$, = ";"} $F[0] = $F[0] - 100; print(@F)' file
```

To edit the file in-place:

```
perl -i -F\; -lane 'BEGIN {$, = ";"} $F[0] = $F[0] - 100; print(@F)' file
```

- `-i`: specifies that files processed by the "<>" construct are to be edited in-place.
- `-F\;`: sets the input field separator to `;`
- `-l`: enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/.
- `-a`: turns on autosplit mode when used with a -n or -p. An implicit split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the -n or -p.
- `n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program.
- `BEGIN {$, = ";"} $F[0] = $F[0] - 100; print(@F)`: sets the output field separator to `;`, assigns the first field its value decreased by 100 and prints the record.

```
% cat file
101; John Bauer;      811-7780831;
102; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627; 
102; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627;
103; Arnold Sipes;    866-4343123;
104; Donald Quinn;    877-2828732;
105; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
105; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
105; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
% perl -F\; -lane 'BEGIN {$, = ";"} $F[0] = $F[0] - 100; print(@F)' file
1; John Bauer;      811-7780831
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627; 
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627
3; Arnold Sipes;    866-4343123
4; Donald Quinn;    877-2828732
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is basically "make first column equal to value - 100". AWK is appropriate for that

```
$ awk -F';' 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}{$1=$1-100;print }' personList.txt  
1; John Bauer;      811-7780831;
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627; 
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627;
3; Arnold Sipes;    866-4343123;
4; Donald Quinn;    877-2828732;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
```

There's no inplace editing, so redirect the output to a new file.

```
$ awk -F';' 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}{$1=$1-100;print }' personList.txt  | tee newFile.txt
1; John Bauer;      811-7780831;
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627; 
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627;
3; Arnold Sipes;    866-4343123;
4; Donald Quinn;    877-2828732;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001;
```

To address what you asked in the comments (making field #4 "Not Available" if it's empty), you could test for 4 characters of class digit using if statement and regex

```
$ awk -F';' 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}{$1=$1-100; if ($4 !~ /[[:digit:]]{4}/) $4=" N/A"  ;print }' personList.txt 

1; John Bauer;      811-7780831; 1001;
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627; N/A;
2; Anthony Higgins; 844-4317627; N/A;
3; Arnold Sipes;    866-4343123; N/A;
4; Donald Quinn;    877-2828732; N/A;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001; 1267;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001; 1273;
5; Roy Jaeger;      551-2323001; 1204;
```

Alternatively you could do something like this with if statement

```
if ( $4 !~ /.*[0-9].*/ )
```

Comment: Thank you so much Serg! What if I had another column, and in occasions the value is NULL. How could I insert something there if the value was NULL.

Comment: Could you post an example to paste.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: Most definitely. Here it is http://paste.ubuntu.com/14880040/

Comment: Done. See my edit

Comment: Thanks Serg. The code you pasted replaces everything even if there's a value. What else can I try? Thanks again

Comment: Are there values with less or greater than 4 digits ? Because that's what the code is doing, it's looking for 4th column where there's no 4 digit pattern

Comment: You could change the `{4}` part to `{1,4}` so that it looks for minimum 1, maximum 4 digits

Comment: gawk version 4 *does* have inplace editing: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace

Comment: At the moment they are all 4 digits.  If I leave it like {4} or {1,4}, when I run it, each value returns "N/A"

Comment: @glennjackman it does, true, but most other versions don't. In addition, Ubuntu versions prior to 15.04  I think come with mawk, which doesn't have inplace editing. So it's better to shoot for portability

Comment: Right, I forgot that Ubuntu doesn't come with gawk installed by default

Comment: @gm_will that's strange, works alright for me here.

Comment: @gm_will ah, there's your problem - you are using `mawk` . . . portability issue. Give me a minute

Comment: @Serg This is for ubuntu, just at the moment I don't have my machine and I'm trying it on Red Hat 6. For sure that's it.

Comment: @gm_will Well, RHEL6 probably also comes with a different awk version. Never tried it though

Comment: @Serg Maybe, it works like a charm, it just doesn't respect if there's a value on the last column.

Comment: @Serg if ( $4 !~ /.*[0-9].*/ ) solved the problem! thank you every much